# How to edit hidden files with dart on windows?

Tags: windows, dart, hidden-files

Windows 10

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  File('C:\\Users\\alexa\\Documents\\test\\my-file.txt').writeAsString("some-text"); // got error if hidden, no error if not hidden
}
```

When I run this code on windows and the file is NOT [hidden](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files-0320fe58-0117-fd59-6851-9b7f9840fdb2) everything works nice.

But when I hide the file I got error:

```
Unhandled Exception: PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\alexa\Documents\test\my-file.txt' (OS Error: Accès refusé.

, errno = 5)
```

Notice that when I run this code on an hidden file I get the data of the file:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> args) {
  File('C:\\Users\\alexa\\Documents\\test\\my-file.txt').readAsStringSync(); // everything works fine here, even on hidden file
}
```

In both case the file was not in read only mode. He had only the [+H attribute](https://home.csulb.edu/%7Emurdock/attrib.html).

> +R - Use the +R option to make a file read-only. Read-only files may be
> read but they can`t be changed or deleted.
>
> -R - Use the -R option to change the file protection attribute back to normal (so it can be read, changed, or deleted).
>
> +A - Use the +A option to set the ARCHIVE attribute of a file. When the +A option is used, this flags the file as available for archiving
> when using the BACKUP or XCOPY commands.
>
> -A - Use the -A option to turn off the ARCHIVE attribute.
>
> +H - With DOS Versions 4 through 6, use the +H option to set the HIDDEN attribute of a file so that it will not appear in a directory
> listing.
>
> -H - Use the -H option to turn off the HIDDEN attribute.
>
> +S - With DOS Versions after Version 4, use the +S option to set the SYSTEM attribute of a file. When the +S option is used, this flags the
> file as a command file used only by DOS. The file will not appear in a
> directory listing. This attribute is generally reserved for
> programmers.
>
> -S - Use the -S option to turn off the SYSTEM attribute.
>
> /S - Use the /S switch to set attributes on subdirectories found
> within the specified path.

[image]

Why can't I edit an hidden file with dart ?

Comment: This is probably a bug.  I suggest [filing an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/52401

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find why you cannot edit an hidden file on windows with dart, so I created an hidden folder and move my file inside this folder and make my file visible.